# O que fazer quando um elemento de UI não pode ser usado por um usuário?

Tags: ux

É comum um usuário não poder usar todos os elementos da interface. Isto pode ocorrer de forma permanente (ou semipermanente, já que alguma configuração ou mudança de permissão pode mudar isto) ou momentânea. Normalmente existem 3 estratégias que podem ser usadas:

1. Deixa o usuário usá-lo e apresenta uma mensagem de erro indicando que ele não pode fazer aquilo
2. proíbe seu uso e marca o objeto com alguma cor que diferencie o estado "proibido" dele
3. esconde por completo o objeto da UI.

Quando e por que usar cada estratégia? Faz diferença se a "proibição" é (semi)permanente ou se é circunstancial? Faz diferença se é web, mobile ou desktop, ou ainda outro dispositivo, sei lá, um painel industrial, por exemplo?

Existe alguma coisa importante que eu não percebi sobre o assunto? Sinta-se livre para complementar o que quiser.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

O @OnoSendai já respondeu muito bem, mas eu gostaria de complementar com algumas coisas que julgo importantes.

**1 Deixa o usuário usá-la e apresenta uma mensagem de erro indicando que ele não pode fazer isto.**

Essa opção é potencialmente a pior para a experiência dos usuários. Se um usuário tentou uma interação, das duas uma: ou ele desejou fazê-la ou foi levado a acreditar que precisava fazê-la. Assim, a tentativa seguida da não-permissão resulta em frustração no primeiro caso e em dificuldade desnecessária no segundo (o que, no mínimo, vai contra o princípio de usabilidade relacionado à eficiência).

**3 Esconde por completo o objeto da UI.**

Embora melhor do que a anterior essa opção tem também alguns problemas, principalmente segundo os princípios de usabilidade relacionados à aprendizagem e à memorização. Se um elemento de interação pode ou não ser apresentado segundo variações contextuais, isso requer que o usuário se lembre de mais informações ("onde foi parar aquele campo mesmo?") e aprenda mais passos para que a interação possa ser eventualmente útil. Há de se fazer testes com usuários para verificar se há um real problema quando essa forma é empregada, mas potencialmente ela vai gerar mais dificuldade para o usuário do que benefício para sua segurança.

**2 Proíbe seu uso e marca o objeto com alguma cor que diferencie o estado "proibido" dele.**

Dentre as opções colocadas, essa talvez seja a melhor para a experiência do usuário quando uma interação não deve ser permitida. O @OnoSendai colocou muito bem a respeito de que pode ser importante para o usuário saber que a interação é possível em outro contexto (isto é, ela existe). De fato, ela é importante também porque facilita que o usuário entenda o porquê da interação não ser permitida naquele momento/contexto. E o contexto da interação é o que torna esse entendimento mais fácil.

Por exemplo, no preenchimento de um formulário em que se escolhe em um botão de seleção (um radio-button) se o usuário é pessoa física ou jurídica (uma empresa), o preenchimento de informações relativas à empresa como o número do Cadastro Nacional de Pessoa Jurídica (CNPJ, no Brasil) deve ser apenas permitido se a escolha no objeto de seleção anterior for pessoa jurídica. A habilitação/desabilitação do campo do número do cadastro está no mesmo contexto do objeto de seleção e a alteração no comportamento pode ser observada e aprendida em uma mesma visualização (mesma tela).

Deve ser possível perceber que ai começam a ser envolvidas outras questões que precisam também ser analisadas no projeto da interação. Nesse exemplo particular, os campos seletor-númerocadastro devem ser colocados suficientemente próximos para que sejam facilmente relacionados pelo usuário.

**Concluindo**

Permitir a interação apenas para indicar (via mensagem de texto ou erro) que o usuário não poderia tê-la tentado é comumente desgastante e provavelmente inútil. As opções melhores são esconder a opção de ação ou simplesmente desabilitá-la. Se a opção por esconder parecer mais apropriada, talvez seja relevante considerar se essa interação não deveria estar em um contexto próprio/separado (em outra janela, por exemplo). Porque talvez faça mais sentido deixar o usuário utilizá-la quando realmente necessário ao invés de escondê-la dele. Finalmente, desabilitar interações pode fazer mais sentido especialmente quando essa impossibilidade de uso decorre de uma ação imediata (ou bastante recente) do usuário, e que pode ser temporária dentro do contexto atual (caso de campos correlacionados, como exemplificado).

Comment: +1 - Especialmente 'Permitir a interação apenas para indicar (via mensagem de texto ou erro) que o usuário não poderia tê-la tentado é comumente desgastante e provavelmente inútil'

Answer (score 17):

Depende da filosofia de experiência de usuário desejada. Em geral, algumas regras são utilizadas como padrão<sup>*[Citation Needed]*</sup>:

- **Função disponível**: Quando a sua validação procedural precisa ser atômica e no final da ação (*late validation*).
- **Objetos desabilitados**: Quando o seu objetivo é demonstrar um *soft block*; O usuário se beneficia com o conhecimento que a função existe, mas algum contexto (segurança, autenticação, disponibilidade do serviço) não permite a ação no momento.
- **Objetos escondidos**: Quando não há benefícios no fato do usuário saber que a funcionalidade está disponível.

*Viewports* com restrições de visibilidade (dispositivos mobile, por exemplo) podem fazer com que objetos cujo comportamento originalmente lhe valeriam uma avaliação do tipo 2 caiam para o tipo 3.

Answer (score 11):

Minha opinião pessoal é a mesma do [Joel Spolsky](http://stackexchange.com/users/4/joel-spolsky).

[**Não esconda nem desabilite.**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html)

Vou deixar a tradução aqui:

> Há muito tempo atrás, virou moda e até recomendação desabilitar itens de menu que não possam ser usados.
>   Não faça isso. Os usuários veem o item do menu que eles querem usar desabilitado, e não têm a menor ideia do que precisa ser feito para que o item do menu volte a funcionar.
>   Ao invés disso, deixe o item habilitado. Se houver algum motivo pelo qual a ação do menu não pode ser completada, o item pode exibir uma mensagem informado o motivo ao usuário.

Tenho uma abordagem alternativa. Se o elemento for um botão grande o suficiente para que haja um texto explicativo embaixo, você pode desabilitar o item. No texto explicativo você diz o motivo.

O mais importante é sempre deixar o usuário ciente da razão de ele não poder usar determinada funcionalidade. Esconder pode deixar usuários confusos, e desabilitar sem explicar o motivo gera frustração. Digo isso porque é o que sinto quando vejo um elemento desabilitado e não sei o porquê.

Comment: Em qualquer situação? Este é ponto central da pergunta. Se o usuário nunca tem acesso a algo, ele deve ficar vendo aquilo? Deve deixar ele babando para saber o que está por traz daquilo? A SE realmente usa muito esta recomendação, mas nem sempre. Olha nos votos. Se você não pode votar no momento, só sabe se clicar. É claro que poderia ter uma informação indicando o motivo da proibição momentânea sem precisar clicar. Por outro lado se você não pode ver os votos positivos e negativos separadamente isto é escondido, e não dá motivo.

Comment: Se o usuário nunca pode usar, acho que é o caso de não exibir mesmo.

Comment: O fundamental é a frase: "O mais importante é sempre deixar o usuário ciente da razão [...]". A questão a se avaliar é se essa ciência é mais bem transmitida antes ou depois de uma ação. Em geral, requerer uma ação adicional apenas para comunicar impossibilidade de uso não é a melhor alternativa, principalmente quando há pré-requisitos "claros" no mesmo contexto (menus "Copiar" ou "Salvar", por exemplo). Mas desabilitar um menu que ofereça uma função mais atômica ("Importar CSV", por exemplo) causará confusão. Por isso, o ideal é avaliar as escolhas de design com os usuários.

Comment: P.S.: Se algo nunca é usado, nem deveria ter sido construído. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira acho que varia conforme o caso. O bigown chamou a atenção para os botões de moderação do Stack Exchange, que vão aparecendo a medida que você ganha reputação. Uma vez que um botão desses aparece, a menos que você perca reputação, ele não desaparece mais.

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro ponto que vejo nessa questão toda é que, por mais que adicionemos referencias, as respostas ainda tem um tom de opinião (inclusive, isso é uma opinião[using ironia]). A usabilidade é uma área mais humana, o que permite entendimentos diferentes em diversos casos, não diferente, sobre esse assunto. Porém, vamos ao que importa, para a pergunta.

Indo diretamente ao meu ponto central sobre o assunto, **pessoas diferentes esperam coisas diferentes de sistemas diferentes**(O que será que eu quis dizer com isso!?). Bom, antes de pensarmos, "vou esconder o elemento? vou exibir o elemento e caso o usuário interaja aviso que ele não pode executar aquela ação? vou mudar o design do elemento indicando que a funcionalidade é 'proibida' para ele?" temos que pensar, "o que o meu usuário alvo quer/espera do sistema?". Ou seja, um usuário de ERP espera determinadas ações do sistema enquanto um usuário de serviços de straming de vídeo esperam coisas totalmente diferentes do sistema, já um usuário de uma determinada rede social espera coisas ainda mais diferentes ao fazer uso do sistema. Um exemplo "vivo" disso é o SO, a comunidade do SO, se não toda, a maioria, é composta por pessoas das áreas tecnológicas, tais pessoas esperam coisas diferentes do SO do que se fossem usuários de áreas mais humanas. Ainda no exemplo do SO, ele usa Gamification para incentivar os usuários a perguntarem e responderem, quando acessamos a página de [privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), vemos tudo que poderemos ter se atingirmos tal pontuação, eles estão claramente fazendo a utilização da 2ª opção citada na pergunta, mas eles tem um proposito por trás disso que é instigar o usuário a responder/perguntar para chegar naquela pontuação e, finalmente, conseguir executar tais ações, já em outra área do site, como as [filas de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review), só ficam visíveis quando o usuário "ganha" permissão para acessar aquela funcionalidade e, mais uma vez, usando a 2º opção da pergunta, o SO desabilita o que o usuário não pode fazer, ainda com a ideia de "provocar" o usuário a, um dia, chegar naquela pontuação e conseguir acesso a funcionalidade.

A resposta mais direta para a pergunta é **depende**. Sim, na pergunta já é entendível que há um depende, afinal é perguntando

> Quando e por que usar cada estratégia? Faz diferença se a "proibição" é (semi)permanente ou se é circunstancial?

Mas, conforme minha abordagem é "impossível" responder um desses questionamentos sem antes pensar, "quem é meu usuário e o que ele quer/espera do sistema?"(sim, estou sendo redundante)

> Deixa o usuário usá-lo e apresenta uma mensagem de erro indicando que ele não pode fazer aquilo?

Sem dúvidas, em todo contexto, essa é a pior opção de todas, está dando para o usuário a impressão que ele pode fazer algo que na verdade ele não pode. É sem dúvidas, uma experiência muito ruim. Imagine abrir um pote de sorvete e encontrar feijão dentro?

> proíbe seu uso e marca o 1objeto com alguma cor que diferencie o estado "proibido" dele?

Novamente, "quem é o usuário do meu sistema?". Exemplo, se é um usuário de um sistema corporativo e ele é um "operador" não há motivos para ele ver o botão gerar relatório financeiro, uma vez que tal item é de interesse de algum gestor, agora, como o exemplo dado acima, se é um usuário que, de alguma forma, ele possa "alcançar" a permissão para executar aquela funcionalidade, é extremamente válido a utilização dessa opção, pois o usuário ficará "provocado" a querer fazer aquela ação, muitas vezes pode ser apenas pelo fato de "eu posso", mas o que vezo nessas situações é o engajamento causado.

> esconde por completo o objeto da UI.

Por fim, se não a opção mais utilizada, uma das, seria esconder os itens da UI. E, mais uma vez a pergunta, "Quem é o meu usuário?", usando o exemplo do usuário de um sistema corporativo, será que escondendo o botão de relatório financeiro não consigo exibir itens de mais interesse para esse usuário, coisas que farão muito mais sentido ele ver, invés de ocupar espaço com algo que ele não pode fazer e não é interesse dele? e no caso do gestor, há necessidade de ver campos onde são "imputados" dados, sendo que quem faz isso é o operador? na maioria dos casos o mais interessante para o gestor é ver gráficos e números bem grandes na tela, ou talvez, em alguns casos, não seja, por isso, "Quem é o meu usuário e o que ele quer/espera do sistema"

---

Pensando em algo mais "técnico", fiz uma pequena análise heurística quanto as 3 opções. Para isso usei as [10 heurísticas de Nielsen](https://helabs.com/artigos/2015/04/10/aprendendo-usabilidade-com-as-10-heuristicas-de-nielsen/):

> Deixa o usuário usá-lo e apresenta uma mensagem de erro indicando que ele não pode fazer aquilo?

**Feedback/Visibilidade de Status do Sistema:**

- Resultado: **Neutro**
- Descrição: Após o usuário tentar executar a ação é retornado mensagem de erro, informando que ele não pode fazer tal ação, ou seja, há feedback, porém, há falha porque não há visibilidade do status do sistema. Está sendo exibido uma função que o usuário não pode executar.

**Liberdade e controle do usuário**

- Resultado: **Negativo**
- Descrição: 
  Não é dada liberdade para o usuário, uma vez que é permitido que o usuário "inicie" uma ação que ele não pode executar. Na verdade, está sendo removido o controle do usuário quanto ao sistema.

**Flexibilidade e eficiência de uso**

- Resultado: **Negativo**
- Descrição: O sistema tem que ser fácil e intuitivo, a partir do momento que se tem elementos na tela e quando o usuário clica ele não sabe se vai executar ou não a ação é perdido toda eficiência, gera uma dúvida, "quando eu clicar no elemento, o que quero vai ou não ser executado?"

**Estética e design minimalista**

- Resultado: **Negativo**
- Descrição: Não deve ser inserida na tela informações desnecessárias, itens não utilizamos, temos que pensar em exibir o melhor para aquele determinado usuário.

> proíbe seu uso e marca o 1objeto com alguma cor que diferencie o estado "proibido" dele?

**Feedback/Visibilidade de Status do Sistema:**

- Resultado: **Positivo**
- Descrição: Deixa visível para o usuário qual o status atual, ao mudar o estilo do elemento para um estilo que denote "desautorização" para aquela função, é dada visibilidade do status, quanto ao feedback, o ideal é informar para o usuário se um dia ele poderá fazer tal ação e, caso sim, o que ele precisa fazer para conseguir.

**Estética e design minimalista**

- Resultado: **Neutro**
- Descrição: Item "relativo ao futuro", o usuário poderá executar tal ação? se sim, há vantagem em ele saber daquele elemento na UI, caso não, o elemento "rouba" espaço de outros itens.

**Flexibilidade e eficiência de uso**

- Resultado: **Neutro para positivo**
- Descrição: É necessário identificar qual a relevância de se exibir um item que o usuário não pode interagir, se houver ganho com isso se torna positivo e traz eficiência.

**Liberdade e controle do usuário**

- Resultado: **Neutro para negativo**
- Descrição: O usuário pode se sentir sem o controle da ferramenta uma vez que são exibidos diversos elementos na UI que ele não pode interagir.

> esconde por completo o objeto da UI.

**Flexibilidade e eficiência de uso**

- Resultado: **Positivo**
- Descrição: É possível exibir itens de maior interesse do usuário na UI e itens, que naquele momento, irão agregar mais valor as tarefas, caso 1 dia faça sentido o usuário ver um determinado elemento a mais na UI aí sim esse deve ser adicionado.

**Estética e design minimalista**

- Resultado: **Positivo**
- Descrição: Toda UI fica voltada apenas para o que o usuário precisa ver, não elementos "desnecessários" ocupando espaço.

**Liberdade e controle do usuário**

- Resultado: **Positivo**
- Descrição: O usuário se sente no "poder" da aplicação uma vez que ele consegue interagir com qualquer elemento em tela.

Comment: Muito bom! Acredito que esse tipo de pergunta deveria ser um `off topic`. Mesmo acreditando que ela não deveria estar aqui, me interesso muito pelo assunto. Me interessando pelo assunto, concordo com seu posicionamento "_em gênero e número igual_". Concordando, +1!

Comment: Gostei da resposta. Ganhou meu +1. :) Agora, gostaria de comentar que, muito embora eu concorde totalmente com você a respeito de que o usuário precisa ser *sempre* considerado, eu não acho que a resposta é realmente "depende". Muitas pessoas já estudam esse assunto há quase 2 décadas, então é possível sim ter um conjunto de boas práticas que indicam o melhor caminho *geral*. Você mesmo faz uma análise nesse sentido ao usar as heurísticas de Nielsen. Ou seja, certamente existe uma solução padrão, que funciona da melhor forma em muitos casos. Mas que deve ser ajustada ao contexto e ao usuário.

Comment: @LuizVieira, concordo com você, talvez eu tenha sido muito "sensacionalista" nos meus "dependes". Como você disse, há estudos e mais estudos sobre o assunto, sem dúvidas há métricas a serem seguidas para os mais diversos casos. Minha ideia central foi colocar o usuário em primeiro lugar. Mais tarde tentarei dar uma ajusta na resposta quanto ao "depende".

Answer (score 1):

A meu ver, depende muito do cenário e o contexto em que o elemento se encontra.

**A opção de apresentar uma mensagem informando ao usuário que ele não tem permissão**

Não sou a favor, pois nos meus 5 anos em que fui do setor de suporte de uma empresa, sempre recebia ligações de clientes, indignados com o fato de:

> Por que existe uma opção em que eu não tenho permissão?

Ouse seja o usuário visualiza a possibilidade de executar uma ação, mas não pode. Isso é frustrante e acaba gerando uma demanda de suporte. Mesmo que venha a se esclarecer, que foi o administrador do sistema que bloqueou o acesso. Ou que o cliente não tem acesso pois a licença não permite.

**Manter o elemento bloqueado**

No caso de um item de menu, eu sou a favor de não exibir, caso o usuário não tenha permissão, pois como o colega Renan disse, seria ruim mostrar algo que não funcione pois está desabilitado, por alguma questão de permissão.

O pior é que se o elemento, é mostrado mas não executa qualquer ação, o usuário pode entender que é um *bug*, do sistema, e de novo será gerado uma demanda de suporte.

**Em outro cenário**

Vamos imaginar uma tela de cadastro de cliente. Temos os seguintes tipos de cliente.

- Pessoa física
- Pessoa jurídica

Sendo que para pessoa física temos CPF e para pessoa jurídica temos CNPJ.

*Já pude observar as seguintes abordagens*

- Criar apenas um elemento que aceite as duas informações.
- Incluir os dois elementos, e desabilitar a digitação de um quando o outro estiver preenchido.
- Criar um elemento select, para que o usuário informe se é pessoa física ou jurídica, para que possa ser apresentado o elemento adequado

Além do campo CNPJ/CPF, temos outras situações como:

- Inscrição Estadual que é apenas para pessoa jurídica
- RG que é apenas para pessoa física

Até mesmo vários outros elementos que podem surgir nesse sentido.

Baseado no que eu falei, sou a favor de criar uma tela independente para Pessoa física e uma tela para pessoa jurídica.

Mesmo que compartilhem de propriedades em comum, e até mesmo possam ser armazenados na mesma tabela no banco de dados. Acho que desta forma diminuímos esses controles de habilitar e desabilitar elementos.

O que a meu ver pode gerar vários problemas, como por exemplo:

Caso eu tenha que manipular a tela de cadastro para incluir um campo que será apenas para pessoa jurídica. Além de eu ter que incluir mais uma condição para habilitar e desabilitar o elemento, corre o risco de eu esquecer de fazer este controle, ou até mesmo atrapalhar algo que já funcione.

Comment: **Nessa situação** acredito que criar telas separadas é desnecessário, muitas vezes vai gerar duplicata de código ou mais verificações, além de dificultar um possível troca de formulário. Sobre _"corre o risco de eu esquecer de fazer este controle, ou até mesmo atrapalhar algo que já funcione."_, pretende fazer uma alteração no sistema e colocar em produção algo que pode não funcionar? Sendo também que, ao dividir a tela, pode ocorrer o mesmo em outras partes. Mas mesmo assim +1 pelo fato de mencionar o fato do suporte